# Js if statement is not working properly

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, if-statement

So I am making this breakout game with the p5js framework, but I am a bit stuck when checking if the ball is hitting the blocks. I have all my block as an object in an array and I loop through the array every frame to check if it collides with the ball but somehow my if statement doesn't work properly.

this is what my loop looks like:

```
for(var i=0; i<blocks.length; i++){
        if(this.x <= (blocks[i].x + 10) && this.x >= (blocks[i].x - 10)){
         //the + and - 10 stand for the length of the block which is 20 and is drawn from the center
            console.log(blocks[i], this.x, this.y);
            if(this.y <= blocks[i].y + 10 && this.y >= blocks[i].y + 5){
            //here the + 10 stands for the height of the block/2 + the height of the ball/2 and the + 5 stands for the height of the height of the block/2
                console.log('yes');
            }
        }
    }
```

You can see that I console.log() the current block and the balls x and y position if its x position meets the requirements but if I log it I get this result:

```
block {x: "70", y: "315", c: "white"} 200 470
//I get a lot more results but this is an example.
```

but this shouldn't be logging because 70+10 < 200.
Also my second console.log() never triggers.

this is what the variables of my ball object look like:

```
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.r = 10;
```

with r as the radius of the ball.

this is what the block object looks like:

```
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
```

I hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that your `block.x` is a String and not a number. You can verify this in the console of a browser:

```js
console.log(200 < "70" + 10) // true
console.log(200 > "70" - 10) // true
```

This is because `"70" + 10` will yield `"7010"`, but `"70" - 10` will yield `60` (very interesting on how JS decides to convert string to number or not in these cases, right?). You'll need to convert your `block.x` and `block.y` to number by using `parseInt()` method. E.g.

```js
console.log(200 < parseInt("70") + 10) // false
```

Comment: Thank you I think this is the answer I will try it later today

Answer (score 0):

```
  block {x: "70", y: "315", c: "white"} 200 470
```

var x: "70" typeof String same as your var y.. 
you can try`parseFloat(x)/parseInt(x)` will change to number.